# Google Drive Live API: Server Export of Collaboration Document

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a requirement to build an application with the following features:

1. Statistical and Source data is presented on simple HTML pages
2. Some missing Source data can be added from that HTML page ( data will be both exact numerical values and discriptive text )
3. Some new Source data can be added from those pages
4. Confirmed and verified data will NOT be editable via the HTML interface
5. Data is stored and made continuously available via the HTML interface
6. Periodically the data added/changed from the interface needs to be pulled back into the source data - but in a VERY controlled way. All data changes and submissions will need verification and checking - and some will trigger re-runs of models ( some of which take hours to run ).

In terms of overview architecture I have:

- Large DB that stores and manages the data - this is designed for import process's and analysis. It is not ideal for web presentation or interface
- Code servers that manipulate the data for imports and analysis
- Frontend server that works as a proxy to add layer of security to S3
- Collection of generated html files on S3 presenting the data required

Before reading about the Google Drive Realtime API my rough plan was to simply serialize data from the HTML interface and post to S3. The import server scripts would then check for new information, grab it, check it, log it and process it into the main data set.

That basic process however would mean that once changes were submitted from the web page - they would be lost from the users view until they had been processed by the backend.

With the Google Drive Realtime API it would appear I could get the best of both worlds.

However for the above to work I would need to be able to access the Collaboration Document in code from the code servers and export the data.

The Realtime API gives javascript access to Export and hand off to a function - however in my use case I want to automate the Export from the Collaboration Document.

The Google Drive SDK does not as far as I can see give any hints on downloading/exporting a file of type "Collaboration File".

What "non-browser-user" triggered methods are there for interfacing with the Collaboration Documents and exporting them?

David

Comment: Please, mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side export is not supported right now.  What you could do is save the realtime model to a regular drive file, and read from that using the standard Drive API.  See https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/models-files for some discussion on different ways to setup interactions between realtime models and Drive Files.

Comment: Is there any plan for that to made available?

Comment: Yes, there are plans to support this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Ali - any idea on timescales?